# nlp: is CRFClassifier.segmentString thread safe?

Tags: java, nlp

I have a web service, the input is a sentence, I want to use CRFClassifier get the segments of this sentence. 
so I used the following code.

```
public class SegmentParser {
    private CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier;
    public SegmentParser() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("sighanCorporaDict", "/Users/zhifan/Downloads/stanford-segmenter-2015-01-30/data");
        props.setProperty("NormalizationTable", "/Users/zhifan/Downloads/stanford-segmenter-2015-01-30/data/norm.simp.utf8");
        props.setProperty("normTableEncoding", "UTF-8");
        props.setProperty("serDictionary", "/Users/zhifan/Downloads/stanford-segmenter-2015-01-30/data/dict-chris6.ser.gz");
        props.setProperty("inputEncoding", "UTF-8");
        props.setProperty("sighanPostProcessing", "true");
        classifier = new CRFClassifier<CoreLabel>(props);
        classifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions("/Users/zhifan/Downloads/stanford-segmenter-2015-01-30/data/ctb.gz", props);
    }

    public List<String> parse(String sentence) {
        return classifier.segmentString(sentence);
    }
}
```

For every web request, I can new SegmentParser().parse(sentence).  Actually the new SegmentParser() needs a long time, so it is a really bad design.

So my question are:

1. Can I initlize 1 instance of SegmentParser for all the requests?  is SegmentParser.parse thread-safe? (I think it can be also said as if  CRFClassifier.segmentString is thread-safe)
2. Generally,  how can I know if a class.method() in Java is thread-safe? 
   as for c++, usually I can think C.f() is thread-safe if f() is declared as the following case. Since the execution of c.f() is indenpent with each other even f() is called with the same C instance.

   class C {
       public void f() const {}
   }